# Opening Notepad text editor from ArcPy/Python?

Tags: arcpy, text, gui

Is it possible to use arcpy to open up an editor (like Notepad) to show a simple text file? I'd like to do this in a tool that generates text which is supposed to be copied and pasted into another text file.

If there is a built-in method of showing text without all the other tool output, I'd prefer that.

Having the text already selected would be a bonus.

Comment: Can you use other modules such as subprocess? If you are just copy and pasting, why not just do that in your script as well?

Comment: Well if they are standard modules, I can use them. Copy/paste into the target file is something that should be done by a human, though.

Comment: Python has several methods for creating, reading, and writing text files.  Why bother opening the text in a text editor only to copy and paste when you can write directly to the receiving text file with Python?

Comment: @gbg inserting into the file should be done by a human who can tell where and how the output must be inserted.

Comment: OK,- I found this link showing how to write the text string to the Windows clipboard.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have python >= 2.4 you could include the subprocess module in your script and call that

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

```
import subprocess
path = r'path/to/your/file.txt'
subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe', path])
```

or the os module will open the file with its default application

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

```
import os
os.startfile(r'path/to/your/file.txt')
```

Comment: `startfile` is convenient because it uses the standard application, but unfortunately it doesn't wait. I'd like to wait for the editor to be closed, though, to remove the temporary file I need to create to show the copy/paste output. `subprocess.call` waits, but I need to know the application name then